# Get KeyChar from key text

Tags: java, swing, awt, keystroke, key-events

I have to work with a string standing for a keystroke (for instance "A", "ENTER", "F4"). From this string I need to get the keychar, the keycode and the key modifiers for the keystroke.

Here is what I do (for F4 for example) :

```
AWTKeyStroke ks = AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke("F4");
System.out.println(ks.getKeyCode());
System.out.println(ks.getKeyModifiers());
System.out.println(ks.getKeyChar());
```

I get :

```
115
0
?
```

keycode and modifiers are OK but whatever keystroke I try I always get ? for the keychar ...

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 comments:

- you don't specify that you typed the key, in which case [pressed is assumed and no character is printed](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/AWTKeyStroke.html#getAWTKeyStroke%28java.lang.String%29)
- there is no valid unicode character for "F4"

If you change your statement to `System.out.println((int)ks.getKeyChar());` you will see that `keyChar` is 65535, which is the value of `KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED`.

You could try `AWTKeyStroke ks = AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke("typed A");` to see that keyChar is `A` and you could also try `AWTKeyStroke ks = AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke("typed F4");` to see that you get an exception.